# Notepad RegEx Find/Replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need some help with Notepad's find and replace command.

Find what:

> "name": "TEXT1" "url": TEXT2"

Replace with:

> < DT >< A HREF="TEXT2" ADD_DATE="1427875766" ICON="" >TEXT1< /A >

I have no idea, how to execute this command and replace "TEXT1" and "TEXT2" to the right place in new sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\1, \2, \3 .... is what you can use to retrieve the captured regex results.

Find this :

```
"name": "([^"]+)" "url": "([^"]+)"
                         ^
                         |
                       I put this extra quote in case you forgot it
```

Replace with that :

```
< DT >< A HREF="\2" ADD_DATE="1427875766" ICON="" >\1< /A >
```

Don't forget to activate regex option.